# Restrict Date/Time Picker

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, datepicker

I'm using the contact form 7 datepicker plugin which works great but i'm looking to limit the values on it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/.

I want for users to be able to use the date picker on my contact form 7 booking forms but i want them to only be able to select a day that is no earlier than 1 day and 1 hour in advance. So if i try to select todays date and todays time, an alert will popup saying that its too early. It has to be 25 hours at the earliest. How would i even begin this with the below plugin code:

time.php file ...

```
 <?php

 class ContactForm7Datepicker_Time {

 static $inline_js = array();

 public static function register() {
    // Register shortcodes
    add_action('wpcf7_init', array(__CLASS__, 'add_shortcodes'));

    // Validations
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_time', array(__CLASS__, 'validation_filter'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_time*', array(__CLASS__, 'validation_filter'), 10, 2);


    // Tag generator
    add_action('load-contact_page_wpcf7-new', array(__CLASS__, 'tag_generator'));
    add_action('load-toplevel_page_wpcf7', array(__CLASS__, 'tag_generator'));

    // Messages
    add_filter('wpcf7_messages', array(__CLASS__, 'messages'));

    // Print inline javascript
    add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'print_inline_js'), 99999);
}

public static function shortcode_handler($tag) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);

    if (empty($tag->name))
        return '';

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error($tag->name);

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class($tag->type, 'wpcf7-date');

    if ($validation_error)
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';

    $atts = array();

    $atts['size'] = $tag->get_size_option('40');
    $atts['maxlength'] = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option($class);
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_option('id', 'id', true);
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option('tabindex', 'int', true);
    $atts['type'] = 'text';

    if ($tag->has_option('readonly'))
        $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';

    if ($tag->is_required())
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';

    $value = (string)reset($tag->values);

    if ($tag->has_option('placeholder') || $tag->has_option('watermark')) {
        $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
        $value = '';
    }

    if (wpcf7_is_posted() && isset($_POST[$tag->name]))
        $value = stripslashes_deep($_POST[$tag->name]);

    $atts['value'] = $value;

    $dpOptions = array();
    $dpOptions['timeFormat'] = str_replace('_', ' ', $tag->get_option('time-format', '', true));
    $dpOptions['firstDay'] = (int)$tag->get_option('first-day', 'int', true);
    $dpOptions['showAnim'] = $tag->get_option('animate', '', true);
    $dpOptions['controlType'] = $tag->get_option('control-type', '', true);

    $dpOptions['showButtonPanel'] = $tag->has_option('buttons');
    $dpOptions['changeMonth'] = $tag->has_option('change-month');
    $dpOptions['changeYear'] = $tag->has_option('change-year');

    foreach (array('minute', 'hour', 'second') as $s) {
        foreach (array('min', 'max') as $m) {
            $dpOptions[$s . ucfirst($m)] = (int)$tag->get_option("$m-$s", 'int', true);
        }

        $dpOptions['step' . ucfirst($s)] = (int)$tag->get_option("step-$s", 'int', true);
    }

    $inline = $tag->has_option('inline');

    if ($inline) {
        $dpOptions['altField'] = "#{$tag->name}_alt";
        $atts['id'] = "{$tag->name}_alt";
    }

    $atts['type'] = $inline ? 'hidden' : 'text';
    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts($atts);

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s %4$s</span>',
        $tag->name, $atts, $validation_error,
        $inline ? "<div id=\"{$tag->name}_timepicker\"></div>" : '');

    $html = apply_filters('cf7dp_time_input', $html);

    $dp_selector = $inline ? '#' . $tag->name . '_timepicker' : $tag->name;

    $dp = new CF7_DateTimePicker('time', $dp_selector, $dpOptions);

    self::$inline_js[] = $dp->generate_code($inline);

    return $html;
}

public static function validation_filter($result, $tag) {
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];

    $value = trim($_POST[$name]);

    if ('time*' == $type && empty($value)) {
        $result['valid'] = false;
        $result['reason'][$name] = wpcf7_get_message('invalid_required');
    }

    if (! empty($value) && ! self::is_valid_date($value)) {
        $result['valid'] = false;
        $result['reason'][$name] = wpcf7_get_message('invalid_time');
    }

    return $result;
}

public static function tag_generator() {
    if (! function_exists( 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator'))
        return;

    wpcf7_add_tag_generator('time',
        __('Time field', 'wpcf7'),
        'wpcf7-tg-pane-time',
        array(__CLASS__, 'tg_pane')
    );
}

public static function tg_pane() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/generators/time.php';
}

public static function add_shortcodes() {
    if (function_exists('wpcf7_add_shortcode')) {
        wpcf7_add_shortcode(array('time', 'time*'), array(__CLASS__, 'shortcode_handler'), true);
    }
}

public static function messages($messages) {
    $messages['invalid_time'] = array(
        'description' => __('The time that the sender entered is invalid'),
        'default' => __('Invalid time supplied.'),
    );

    return $messages;
}

public static function print_inline_js() {
    if (! wp_script_is('jquery-ui-timepicker', 'done') || empty(self::$inline_js))
        return;

    $out = implode("\n\t", self::$inline_js);
    $out = "jQuery(function($){\n\t$out\n});";

    echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n{$out}\n</script>\n";
}

private static function animate_dropdown() {
    $html = "<select id=\"animate\">\n";

    foreach (CF7_DateTimePicker::$effects as $val) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($val) . '">' . ucfirst($val) . '</option>';
    }

    $html .= "</select>";

    echo $html;
}

private static function is_valid_date($value) {
    $valid = strtotime($value) ? true : false;
    return apply_filters( 'cf7dp_is_valid_time', $valid, $value );
}
}

ContactForm7Datepicker_Time::register();
```

date.php ...

```
 <?php

 class ContactForm7Datepicker_Date {

static $inline_js = array();

public static function register() {
    // Register shortcodes
    add_action('wpcf7_init', array(__CLASS__, 'add_shortcodes'));

    remove_filter('wpcf7_validate_date', 'wpcf7_date_validation_filter', 10);
    remove_filter('wpcf7_validate_date*', 'wpcf7_date_validation_filter', 10);
    remove_filter('wpcf7_messages', 'wpcf7_date_messages');
    remove_action('admin_init', 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator_date', 19);

    // Validations
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_date', array(__CLASS__, 'validation_filter'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_date*', array(__CLASS__, 'validation_filter'), 10, 2);


    // Tag generator
    add_action('load-contact_page_wpcf7-new', array(__CLASS__, 'tag_generator'));
    add_action('load-toplevel_page_wpcf7', array(__CLASS__, 'tag_generator'));

    // Messages
    add_filter('wpcf7_messages', array(__CLASS__, 'messages'));

    // Print inline javascript
    add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'print_inline_js'), 99999);
}

public static function shortcode_handler($tag) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);

    if (empty($tag->name))
        return '';

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error($tag->name);

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class($tag->type, 'wpcf7-date');

    if ($validation_error)
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';

    $atts = array();

    $atts['size'] = $tag->get_size_option('40');
    $atts['maxlength'] = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option($class);
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_option('id', 'id', true);
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option('tabindex', 'int', true);
    $atts['type'] = 'text';

    if ($tag->has_option('readonly'))
        $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';

    if ($tag->is_required())
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';

    $value = (string)reset($tag->values);

    if ($tag->has_option('placeholder') || $tag->has_option('watermark')) {
        $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
        $value = '';
    }

    if (wpcf7_is_posted() && isset($_POST[$tag->name]))
        $value = stripslashes_deep($_POST[$tag->name]);

    $atts['value'] = $value;

    $dpOptions = array();
    $dpOptions['dateFormat'] = str_replace('_', ' ', $tag->get_option('date-format', '', true));
    $dpOptions['minDate'] = $tag->get_option('min-date', '', true);
    $dpOptions['maxDate'] = $tag->get_option('max-date', '', true);
    $dpOptions['firstDay'] = (int)$tag->get_option('first-day', 'int', true);
    $dpOptions['showAnim'] = $tag->get_option('animate', '', true);
    $dpOptions['yearRange'] = str_replace('-', ':', $tag->get_option('year-range', '', true));
    $dpOptions['numberOfMonths'] = (int)$tag->get_option('months', 'int', true);

    $dpOptions['showButtonPanel'] = $tag->has_option('buttons');
    $dpOptions['changeMonth'] = $tag->has_option('change-month');
    $dpOptions['changeYear'] = $tag->has_option('change-year');
    $dpOptions['noWeekends'] = $tag->has_option('no-weekends');

    $inline = $tag->has_option('inline');

    if ($inline) {
        $dpOptions['altField'] = "#{$tag->name}_alt";
        $atts['id'] = "{$tag->name}_alt";
    }

    $atts['type'] = $inline ? 'hidden' : 'text';
    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts($atts);

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s %4$s</span>',
        $tag->name, $atts, $validation_error,
        $inline ? "<div id=\"{$tag->name}_datepicker\"></div>" : '');

    $html = apply_filters('cf7dp_date_input', $html);

    $dp_selector = $inline ? '#' . $tag->name . '_datepicker' : $tag->name;

    $dp = new CF7_DateTimePicker('date', $dp_selector, $dpOptions);
    self::$inline_js[] = $dp->generate_code($inline);

    return $html;
}

public static function validation_filter($result, $tag) {
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];

    $value = trim($_POST[$name]);

    if ('date*' == $type && empty($value)) {
        $result['valid'] = false;
        $result['reason'][$name] = wpcf7_get_message('invalid_required');
    }

    if (! empty($value) && ! self::is_valid_date($value)) {
        $result['valid'] = false;
        $result['reason'][$name] = wpcf7_get_message('invalid_date');
    }

    return $result;
}

public static function tag_generator() {
    if (! function_exists( 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator'))
        return;

    wpcf7_add_tag_generator('date',
        __('Date field', 'wpcf7'),
        'wpcf7-tg-pane-date',
        array(__CLASS__, 'tg_pane')
    );
}

public static function tg_pane() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/generators/date.php';
}

public static function add_shortcodes() {
    if (function_exists('wpcf7_add_shortcode')) {
        // Remove Contact Form 7's date module
        wpcf7_remove_shortcode('date');
        wpcf7_remove_shortcode('date*');

        wpcf7_add_shortcode(array('date', 'date*'), array(__CLASS__, 'shortcode_handler'), true);
    }
}

public static function messages($messages) {
    $messages['invalid_date'] = array(
        'description' => __('The date that the sender entered is invalid'),
        'default' => __('Invalid date supplied.'),
    );

    return $messages;
}

public static function print_inline_js() {
    if (! wp_script_is('jquery-ui-datepicker', 'done') || empty(self::$inline_js))
        return;

    $out = implode("\n\t", self::$inline_js);
    $out = "jQuery(function($){\n\t$out\n});";

    echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n{$out}\n</script>\n";
}

private static function animate_dropdown() {
    $html = "<select id=\"animate\">\n";

    foreach (CF7_DateTimePicker::$effects as $val) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($val) . '">' . ucfirst($val) . '</option>';
    }

    $html .= "</select>";

    echo $html;
}

private static function is_valid_date($value) {
    $valid = strtotime($value) ? true : false;

    if (! $valid) {
        // Validate dd/mm/yy
        $new_value = str_replace('/', '-', $value);
        $valid = strtotime($new_value) ? true : false;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'cf7dp_is_valid_date', $valid, $value );
 }
 }

 ContactForm7Datepicker_Date::register();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the shortcodes within contact form 7 for this, i.e. min-day:1. Hope this helps someone else.